# html5 section with two horizontal divs

Tags: html, alignment

I need a `<section></section>` that consists of the left and the right parts. The left part is only a single string—the date. The right part should contain something like:

```
<span>title</span>
<p>a lot of text of variable lenght</p>
```

Should I use `<div>`s within a section? The text from the right part should stay on the right part only (so I can't use `float:left;` alone on the left part).

Here is my solution with no `<section>`s, but it doesn't work for 100%, the text goes to the left after the height of 10px (see the code below).

```
    <div style="overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid red; padding:5px; ">
        <div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 10px; color:blue;">right</div>
        <div style="">
            <span style="color:blue;">Lorem ipsum</span>
            <p>a lot of text of variable lenght</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I optimize the code and make it HTML5 with no mistakes, if found some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `margin-left:100px;` on the right part, and get rid of the height on the left ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/tbtq4/)):

```
<section style="display:block; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid red; padding:5px; ">
    <aside style="display:block; float: left; width: 100px; color:blue;">right</aside>
    <div style="margin-left:100px;">
        <span style="color:blue;">Lorem ipsum</span>
        <p>a lot of text of variable lenght</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `float: left'` one `div` you should `float: right;` the other for this to show properly in some versions of Internet Explorer and probably other browsers too.

Comment: Just put it into style="    ". Didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

The modern style would be to use the CSS3 box model ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/AMe6k/)):

```
<style type="text/css">
#horbox {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -khtml-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-box;
    display: -o-box;
    display: box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -khtml-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
    -o-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
}
</style>
<div id="horbox" style="border: 1px solid red; padding:5px;">
    <div style="width: 100px; color:blue;">right</div>
    <div>
        <span style="color:blue;">Lorem ipsum</span>
        <p>a lot of text of variable lenght</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the CSS3 box model is actually not yet supported by all browsers. With Firefox 13, e.g. the display is as wanted.

Comment: First, it is known as the Flexible Box Layout Module, or Flexbox. Also, the syntax you provided is outdated ([old](http://w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/), [new](http://w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/)), and `display:box;` ([spec](http://w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/#overview)) has been replaced with `display:flex;` ([spec](http://w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-containers)) and `box-orient` ([spec](http://w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/#orientation)) has been replaced with several new properties ([spec](http://w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#ordering-and-orientation)).